# How validate domain object in controller input filled by Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

For example I have:

```
@PostMapping("/person/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public boolean isAdmin(@PathVariable("id") Person person) {
  return person != null && person.isAdmin();
}
```

How I can get same result using Validation?
This not works for me, but I look up for something like this, without manual checking in method body. Is there way for doing so?

```
@PostMapping("/person/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public boolean isAdmin(@PathVariable("id") @NotNull Person person) {
  return person.isAdmin();
}
```

Comment: First can you keep object in `PathVariable`? if so how does your post http request would look like?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use javax.validation.Valid and add constraints to your Person pojo: javax.validation.constraints.Email/NotBlank/NotNull;

```
public class Person {

    @NotNull
    private Long id;
    /* here getters and setters...*/
}
```

In your controller:

```
@PostMapping("/person/{id}")
@ResponseBody
public boolean isAdmin(@Valid @RequestBody Person person) {
  return person.isAdmin();
}
```

[see my github](https://github.com/PalituxD/message-delivery-microservice/blob/message-delivery-application/message-delivery-application/src/main/java/org/justfoolingaround/apps/messagedelivery/web/v1/PostalController.java)